# GROUP BY a certain value on rows used as columns

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, pivot

I have a table of survey data where lines of results are separated into many rows by, each having their own variable name.

My table looks like this:

```
data_id  data_content   var_name          var_line
1        1              SERIAL            1
2        2              GND.AGE           1
3        3              GND.NEWS.FREQ     1
4        2              SERIAL            2
5        3              GND.AGE           2
6        3              GND.NEWS.FREQ     2
7        3              SERIAL            3
8        3              GND.AGE           3
9        4              GND.NEWS.FREQ     3
```

Here is my current query to retrieve the total number of answers for every possible answer of GND.NEWS.FREQ. As in the total number:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as total
  FROM `data`
 WHERE `var_name` = 'GND.NEWS.FREQ'
 GROUP BY `data_content`
```

Now I need to add the functionality to only return answers where GND.AGE for example is 3. So basically treat all rows where var_line = 1 as a single row.

I have looked up pivot tables but I'm not sure how to add that into my current query.

I would like to do this in one query if possible but I wouldn't mind doing something like getting var_line IDs in a separate query.

Comment: Have a look at these links: [MySQL pivot tables (transform rows to columns)](http://buysql.com/mysql/12-how-to-pivot-tables.html), [Dynamic pivot tables (transform rows to columns)](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL does not have a `PIVOT` function which is basically what you are trying to do. So you will need to use an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement. If you have a unknown number of `var_name` values that you want to turn into columns, then you can use prepared statements:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when var_name = ''',
      var_name,
      ''' then var_line end) AS ',
      replace(var_name, '.', '_')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM data;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT data_content,', @sql, ' 
                  from data
                  group by data_content
                  ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aeb7a/5)

Comment: Thanks bluefeet, that's pretty complicated but looks to be what I'm after.

Comment: After going back to this query I'm getting an error for the prepare bit.

'error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from data group by data_content' at line 2'

Any help would be great, cheers.

Comment: can you edit a sql fiddle and post your code?  My version appears to be working in the demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aeb7a/5.   What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Yeah, sure http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b464b/1/2. There is a lot more data but I had to remove a lot from the export. I think it's 5.1.65.

Comment: @user1734319 you are hitting the limit length of the `group_concat` function - you need to reset the length limit -- see this fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b464b/3